# How to set the number of the first citation?

Tags: bibliographies, numbering, natbib, counters

I am using BibTeX and `natbib` for my citations. In the bibliography the first entry usually starts with [1]. Now I would like to shift all the numbers in the bibliography and text by a certain offset, e.g. 15, so that the first item is called 16 in this document.

Answer (score 9):

I'm not sure why you want to do this (there are various packages that deal with multiple/subdivided bibliographies), but you could use the [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) package to append `natbib`'s definition of the `thebibliography` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\apptocmd{\thebibliography}{\global\c@NAT@ctr 15\relax}{}{}
\makeatother

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
@misc{B02,
  author = {Buthor, B.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Bravo},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

Some text \citep{A01,B02}.

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You saved my day! I want to add that this solution also worked for me for a 'revtex' document class, which in fact was derived from 'natbib'.