# Continuing (and preserved) reference numbers with bibunits

Tags: bibtex, numbering, natbib, subdividing, bibunits

I am trying to have two separate bibliographies that may share common references with the `bibunits` package. If I use a certain reference in `bibunit` 1, I want its number to be continued in `bibunit` 2. Additionally, I want references unique to `bibunit` 2 to start numbering at the next integer in the reference sequence ending in `bibunit` 1. The MWE below causes the two bibliographies to be numbered

> [1]
>
> [2]
>
> [3]
>
> ---
>
> [1]
>
> [2]

and what I want is

> [1]
>
> [2]
>
> [3]
>
> ---
>
> [2]
>
> [4]

Is this possible with `Bibtex`? I know `biblatex` can probably do this but I don't have time to migrate at the moment.

Interrupting edit: I made the switch to `Biblatex` in the end. That package is fantastic. The reason I thought I had a daunting chore in making the switch was Mendeley's .bib file contained a key `O'Lastname`. Every time I tried to switch, Biblatex would protest and I couldn't figure out why.

This question is now moot, but I'll leave it open in case someone answers it one day and another party finds that answer useful.

Here's the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{bibunits}


\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
@misc{B02,
  author = {Buthor, B.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Bravo},
}
@misc{D04,
  author = {Duthor, D.},
  year = {2004},
  title = {Delta},
}
@misc{C03,
  author = {Cuthor, C.},
  year = {2003},
  title = {Charlie},
}

\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{bibunit}[plainnat]
    \nocite{A01,B02,C03}
    \putbib[\jobname]
\end{bibunit}



\begin{bibunit}[plainnat]
    \nocite{B02,D04}
    \putbib[\jobname]
 \end{bibunit}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is essentially a duplicate of this question: [How to change the starting reference number in Natbib in a given bibunit?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/84707). It won't set the number automatically, but is easy enough to add the appropriate start number for the second bibunit in the final stages of the document preparation.

Comment: It is actually a different question. I would like to include some refs in both bibunits and maintain citation numbers across them. Additionally, the solution provided to that question does not work in my document (just like it did not work for the OP): I get a "You can't use a prefix with `the character .' \begin{thebibliography}" error in bu2.bbl if I try.

Comment: Oh, ok. I misunderstood the question. (No longer relevant, but the linked answer does work with your example document.)

Comment: It works with the MWE, but it does not work with my real document. I have no idea why. The error does not tell me much and I cannot reproduce it without basically uploading my paper being prepped for publication (a big no-no)

Comment: Based on the comments and edit, I think we're best finding a way to close this. I'll mark as a dupe (as that apparently works for the MWE).