# Change bibliography starting number with revtex

Tags: bibliographies, numbering

I want my bibliography to start at another number, not at 1.

I saw this solution [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114420/change-bibliography-starting-number)  that works with articles, but I am using revtex4-1 ... 
(and I stole their minimal example :-))

```
\documentclass{revtex4-1}

\begin{document}


Let us cite \cite{a1},  \cite{a2} and \cite{a3}.

\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\makeatletter
\addtocounter{\@listctr}{8}
\makeatother

\bibitem{a1}
A1
\bibitem{a2}
A2
\bibitem{a3}
A3
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Would be great if you could help me with this.

Comment: You could try with `\addtocounter{NAT@ctr}{8}` instead of `\addtocounter{\@listctr}{8}`, but I'm not sure how safe it is.

Comment: see also this question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84707/how-to-change-the-starting-reference-number-in-natbib-in-a-given-bibunit

Comment: That works! Thanks a lot for this speedy response!! Awesome!

Answer (score 2):

Using "thebibliography" the counter name for the `revtex4-1` class is:

```
\addtocounter{NAT@ctr}{8}
```