# Change bibliography starting number for document class apsrev

Tags: bibtex, counters

I am currently using \begin{thebibliography} for my references at the end of a scientific paper. 
The numbers of the citations go from [1] to [10], as usual.

I would like to change this. 
I would like that the starting number were [11] to [20] for the citations.
(For me, such situations frequently arise when I want to split a single latex-document into 'main text' and separate 'Supplemental Material', where the 'Supplemental Material' should have its own bibliography of additional references.)

This question has been asked for document class 'article'
[Change bibliography starting number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114420/change-bibliography-starting-number), 
but the solution proposed there does not work for document class 'apsrev'.

I suspect the reason is the name of the internal counter. 
I tried 
 - @listctr
 - enumiv, 
both did not work.

Here is what I got.
Using

```latex
    \begin{thebibliography}{42}
    \setcounter{enumiv}{11}
```

simply has no effect: references are still numbered [1]-[10].
Nothing suspicious in the log-file.

Using

```latex
    \begin{thebibliography}{42}
    \makeatletter
    \addtocounter{\@listctr}{11}
    \makeatother
```

gives an error message

```
    ! Undefined control sequence.
    <argument> c@\@listctr                           
    l.2005 \addtocounter{\@listctr}{36}

    The control sequence at the end of the top line
    of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
    misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
    spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
    and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

    ! Undefined control sequence.
     ...rrmessage  LaTeX Error: No counter '\@listctr 
                                                      ' defined.
    See the LaTeX ...
    l.2005 \addtocounter{\@listctr}{36}
```

Does anybody know the name of the counter in \thebibliography for 'apsrev' documents?

[A quick-fix would also be fine, even if it involves manual steps, since this is already the final ready-to-print version.]

Comment: You wrote, "I tried - @listctr - enumiv, both did not work." Please tell us in more exacting detail what precisely you tried -- and what "did not work" entails: A warning message, an error message? If so, what does the message say?

Comment: Thanks, Mico, you are right: I added information.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer:
My document class 'revtex' was derived from 'natbib'.

The solution for 'natbib' was previously described here:
[How to set the number of the first citation?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69675/how-to-set-the-number-of-the-first-citation)

I quote from that solution

```
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\apptocmd{\thebibliography}{\global\c@NAT@ctr 15\relax}{}{}
\makeatother
```